# How can I globally set the store type for TimeSpan properties in EF?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-4.3

I have a `DbContext` class which adds various entity configurations to the model builder during `OnModelCreating`. This context works great when running against SQL Server, but fails against SQL CE because some of the entities contains `TimeSpan` properties.

Is it possible to modify the configurations such that the store type is set to something appropriate (such as `nvarchar(30)`) during `OnModelCreating` when the database is SQL CE?

In my main application, I have a `DbContext` like so:

```
public class MyDbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity1Config());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity2Config());
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Entity3Config());
        // Lots more entity and complex type configurations here.
    }
}
```

That `DbContext` runs against a full SQL Server. In my tests, I would like to run against SQL CE rather than SQL Server Express. Ideally, I would like to override the offending pieces of configuration with a convention or explicit overrides like so:

```
public class MyTestingDbContext : MyDbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Entity1>()     
            .Property(x => x.Duration)     
            .HasColumnType("nvarchar(30) not null");
    }
}
```

To be clear, I'm only interested in solutions that do not involve directly modifying the original `DbContext` class or it's entities.

---

*NOTE: There appears to be a convention in the `ModelBuilder` that already does SQL CE-specific processing for the `MaxLength` attribute but it is mainly implemented using internal classes. (Boooo!)*

Comment: SQL CE only support nvarchar, not varchar

Comment: I am working on exactly the same thing, but currently I have attributes to apply types on the handler. When I try to override the properties I get a message `Conflicting configuration settings were specified for column 'MyColumn' on table 'MyTable'` which makes sense but it would be *very* useful to be able to override that.

Comment: @glenatron I've resotred to using SQL Server 2012's LocalDB instead of SQL CE. All my problems went away!

Answer (score 0):

You can configure that both by Fluent Interface, calling [DateTimePropertyConfiguration.HasColumnType Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.modelconfiguration.configuration.datetimepropertyconfiguration.hascolumntype%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)

```
        modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
            .Property(x=> x.Duration)
            .HasColumnType("Varchar(30) NOT NULL");
```

Or via [ColumnAttribute.DbType property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.mapping.columnattribute.dbtype.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't do what I need. I'll make my question more relevant - you've prompted me to realise I missed out something important.